# UWP Can't Get Method when i add services reference

Tags: xamarin, soap, uwp

I have to call SOAP Webservice. But it can't call at PCL. so I use dependencyservice in Android & UWP

Android can call SOAP Webservice. but when I call add services reference in xxx.UWP, It can't call Method( = Operation) at my WSDL site.

HOW CAN CALL WEB SERVICE (SOAP) IN UWP?? PLEASE HELP ME......

**This is Dependency code**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(XXXXX.UWP.DependencyService.GetWI))]

namespace XXXXX.UWP.DependencyService
{
    public class GetWI : Interface.IGetWI
    {
        public string[] getWIValues(string item)
        {    
            GET_WI.WISWRProviderClient Client = new GET_WI.WISWRProviderClient();
            return
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBkMb.png)

Comment: Have you connected to SOAP service?  you can use Visual Studio's "Connected Services" - "Add Service Reference" context menu.

Comment: Yes I already Tried "Add Service Reference" but I tired this, It can't make Operation that in Services... Only In UWP!

Comment: Have you tried create uwp project and test if the SOAP service is available?

Comment: Yes, Another SOAP Service can get Operation. But SOAP Service that I have to use can't get Operation.... The difference is ""targetNamespace"". available SOAP TargetNameSpace is URL But my SOAP TargetNameSpace is xxx:yyy format..

Comment: Could you share your dependency service code?

Comment: i'cant share Soap URL but I can show my situation
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/390695#Comment_390695

Comment: If you could call the method in uwp platform, I think you could also call method in the share project with dependency service, Have you set the break point and check the SOAP method called?

Comment: is that mean 
""GET_WI.WISWRProviderClient Client = new GET_WI.WISWRProviderClient(binding, address);""
call dependency service??
i tried it, but i can't call method 'getWIvalues'.

Comment: Correct, You need create method in dependency service then call above indirectly.

Comment: how to create method in dependency service? is it possible to make SOAP service?

Comment: For costuming dependency service please refer this  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Comment: I already use Dependency System, Android & UWP. Android can call method but UWP can't call Method....

Comment: The better way is share your dependency service code, and please remove sensitive information.

Comment: Post Code below question. It is only Access local network. so if i give you URL, you can't access SOAP service.

Comment: I'm not that mean, I mean you could share the code that dependency service implementation in your uwp platform, just like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#universal-windows-platform).

Comment: I post the code that use Dependency Service code in UWP, is that right??

Comment: From your comment, I suppose the issue occur in the `DependencyService` , because `getWIValues` method has never called.

Comment: Could you get `Client` instance?

Comment: Yes.. When I use "Add Service Reference", the getWIValues never generated... so I can't call the getWIValues. 
+ I post the Client debugging value

Comment: Could you check if this  `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(XXXXX.UWP.DependencyService.GetWI))]` is correct?

Comment: And the the interface is strange  (`Interface.IGetWI`).

Comment: I develop Xamarin Forms. so Interface code is in PCL Project.

Comment: if you have created the interface file in the share project why can't we see the the 
 share project's namesapce in above code?

Comment: is that mean
Interface.IGetWI --> xxxx.Interface.IGetIWI??(xxxx is shared project)

Comment: Correct, it should be contained the full namesapce.

Comment: It is also Same..... I appreciate your Reply. Thank you....

Comment: No bother, if you want I could create Dependency code sample for you.

Comment: please feel free to say so.

Comment: OH~~ Thank you Nico! My Email Address is Sanghyun8039@gmail.com Yeah

Comment: And I have Some Question Nico.
Is there any difference SOAP Call UWP & Android. When I search that, Android use .netframework 4.xx but UWP doen't use .netframework. 
is it right? so in UWP i can't use System.Web.Service.

Comment: Sorry man, we have policy, currently we have not provided email support.

Comment: UWP has supported SOAP, if you could use it in uwp platform, it also could be used in xamarin.uwp.

Comment: Okay Thank you.. I honor to Know you through this question. if i have some problem  , Could I contact you?

Comment: Of course, please feel free to say so.

Comment: I just make a SOAP lib for uwp app, and it works, please note the you need asynchronous  call SOAP method in uwp.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200216/discussion-on-question-by-cocoadrinker-uwp-cant-get-method-when-i-add-services).